# Header Link function not working. Problem with bloginfo()

Tags: categories, headers, bloginfo

I'm writing a function to make all of my header images link to their respective home pages. I wrote this function:

```
    function get_category_location(){
    $header = get_category_header();
    $home = bloginfo('url');

    if ($header == 'wth') {
        $location = $home . "/wth/" ;
    }

    else if ($header == 'campus' || $header == 'tech') {
        $location = get_category_link();
    }

    else {$location = $home;}

    return $location;

}
```

so when you click a header in the wth section of our site $header should equal 'wth' and $home should equal 'http://dev.reesenews.org' and so location should be set to 'http://dev.reesenews.org/wth/'

as far as I can tell $header and $home are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are storing the value into a variable you need to use

```
get_bloginfo('url')
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo